# Android ACTION_SEND - link to Play Market

Tags: android, вконтакте, android-intent

Пытаюсь передать через `Intent.Action_SEND` ссылку  на приложение в Play Market, она приходит на стену просто как ссылка. Скажите, возможно ли  с  помощью `Action_SEND` сделать share для Вконтакте, чтобы он выглядел в таком формате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или такого результата можно добиться только последствием использования VKSDK?

---

Воспользовавшись родным клиентом ВК `Intent.ACTION_SEND` все-таки показал ссылку. Проблему только с изоражением. Google+ достает скриншот из маркета, а ВК не добавляет никакого изображения

---

Добавлю, что если пытаться делать `Intent.ACTION_Send` и выбрать Google+, то текст распознается как ссылка и будет желаемый результат. Можно ли как-то добиться этого с Вконтакте?

Comment: зарегистрируйте аккаунт, вместо того, чтобы каждый раз создавать нового пользователя ради уточнения вопроса.